# how to build a proxy server with java

Tags: java, sockets

Out Company has a new project.

We will build proxy server .

I use Java'ssocket to get html text from the url.

then I must parse the html text.  like these tags: a,frame,iframe,img,script,link...

I have solved these problems.
But now the JavaScript has do some action in the form . It will change the form's action.

how to solve these problems.

It's a hard job to me

My English is not so good

Comment: A proxy server doesn't do anything with the content it receives, it simply forwards data, so I don't understand your problem.

Comment: I use proxy server to monitor the operators' action. It get html text to show the html page. The oparators does not want to change the old operations. I must parse the html text.

Comment: I can't follow your conclusion to _"I must parse the html text"_. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: A proxy server usually doesn't change what passes through it. That's why it's a "proxy" (= act as if it were someone else). So we expect you to download HTML and then send it to the browser of the operator where the JavaScript will be executed. Proxy just copies data around, it never changes this data or tries to understand it.

Comment: for example, if I do not parse the html text. The hyperlink is the old hyperlink,  I change it to the proxy hyperlink. Then I will know the operator's next action.  or it does not pass my proxy server.

Comment: Proxies don't change links. You set the proxy server in the browser or in the OS, so **all** (HTTP) traffic flows through the proxy, so when you request a web page, the browser requests that page on the proxy, while the proxy connects to the origin(al) server. If you don't get these fundamentals, I really doubt you should be writing a proxy server, no offense.

Comment: but the proxy server is writen by myself.  I must parse the html to let the request can get it.

Answer (score 0):

add this after you run your javascript:

```
document.formName.action = "/actionLink";
```

Comment: Can you give a little explanation as to why this could be a solution?  It might help the OP understand a little bit better.